# Secure a public REST API

Tags: javascript, security, api, rest

I'm providing a service on my site and display advertising to provide it for free. Currently, I'm using standard synchronous POST requests : the user submit the form, my server is processing the result page and display it.
Due to some performance reason, I want to make my site asynchronous : create a REST/JSON API that will be queried from the user browser using Javascript, returns the service result that will be processed by the javascript code on my site to display it. My concern is that I don't want to let anyone use this API (which could be discovered easily by using some HTTP proxy).

Did you already faced this kind of issue ?

Thank you

Comment: It may help to tell us what language / framework / stack you are using server-side, and then we can suggest authentication/authorisation options for you. Any Javascript / JSON / REST / AJAX is largely irrelevant; this is a problem that is solved on the server by IDing the user and knowing which parts of the data they may have access to.

Comment: Server-side is ASP.NET and client side is Ajax. The users are totally anonymous...

Comment: With totally anonymous users, you cannot acheive this, as all users look the same and therefore implicitly have the same rights. You need to introduce authentication and authorisation on the server-side. Otherwise you can only make it more difficult, but never impossible.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to implement an authentication module.  I've used 2 different (java centric) approaches to secure RESTful web services.

I've used [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) for some basic HTTP authentication and would work if the services you are implementing are deployed to a Java Servlet Container or Application server.  It's fairly lightweight and easy to get started.

Currently we're using [OpenAM](http://forgerock.com/openam.html) for our services which is similar to the Spring module in theory, but takes a different approach.  In my opinion, it's more robust and more enterprise level, but takes longer to learn, set up, and configure.

Either approach will allow you to secure access to your RESTful API (urls).